# list of list concept in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I solved the below problem using nested `while` loops. Is there a way to solve the problem in a simple, Pythonic way?

Question:

> Define a procedure that takes in a string of numbers from `1`-`9` and outputs a list with the following parameters:
>
> - Every number in the string should be inserted into the list.
> - If a number `x` in the string is less than or equal to the preceding number `y`, the number `x` should be inserted into a sublist.
> - Continue adding the following numbers to the sublist until reaching a number `z` that is greater than the number `y`.
> - Then add this number `z` to the normal list and continue.
>
> They are comparing the subsequent against the previous digit.
>
> For example:
>
> ```
> string = '543987'
> result = [5,[4,3],9,[8,7]]
>
> string= '987654321'
> result = [9,[8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1]]
>
> string = '455532123266'
> result = [4, 5, [5, 5, 3, 2, 1, 2, 3, 2], 6, [6]]
> ```

My code:

```
def numbers_in_lists(string):
    array = []
    for i in string:
        array.append(int(i))
    temp_list = []
    final_list = [array[0]]    
    i = 0
    while i+1 < len(array):
        if array[i] >= array[i+1]:
            j = 0
            while j+1 < len(array[i:]) and array[i] >= array[i:][j+1]:
                temp_list.append(array[i:][j+1])
                j += 1
            final_list.append(temp_list)
            i += len(temp_list)
            temp_list = []            
        else:
            final_list.append(array[i+1])
            i += 1            
    #print final_list
    return final_list

string = '543987'

print numbers_in_lists(string)
[5, [4, 3], 9, [8, 7]]
```

Comment: What should happen with `'545'`, your code prints `[5, [4, 5]]`

Comment: and what should happen with `'567'`, your code prints `[5, 6, 7]`

Comment: both of these are at odds with your written explanation

Comment: @AnttiHaapala - '545' should give an output like this : '[5, [4], 5]'

Comment: @AnttiHaapala I don't think the explanation is unclear; those results are what I would expect.

Comment: @dangerous I disagree - `z == 5` **is not** greater than `y == 5`, therefore it should be in the sublist.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala - for 567, the condition is the same. it should return [5,6,7].

Comment: @jonrsharpe  in the case of [5,4,5] -> [5, [4,5]]. sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @jonrsharpe my question was about that is the *preceding digit the one preceding the current digit or the entire sublist*, and the other being that are there empty lists or no.

Comment: @dangerous Updated my answer according to the change :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can certainly simplify the approach; I would do it as follows:

```
def numbers_in_lists(string):
    """Describe what it does here!""" 
    output = []
    sublist = []
    for num in map(int, string):
        if not output or num > output[-1]:
            if sublist:
                output.append(sublist)
                sublist = []
            output.append(num)
        else:
            sublist.append(num)
    if sublist:
        output.append(sublist)
    return output
```

In use:

```
>>> numbers_in_lists('543987')
[5, [4, 3], 9, [8, 7]]
>>> numbers_in_lists('987654321')
[9, [8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]]
>>> numbers_in_lists('455532123266')
[4, 5, [5, 5, 3, 2, 1, 2, 3, 2], 6, [6]]
```

Comment: I couldnt understand this line of code what is this condition doing "  if not output or num >= output[-1]:"

Comment: @dangerous can you be more specific; what part of it do you not understand? Note you can use backticks `\`` to format code in comments.

Comment: `if not output or num >= output[-1]:` I couldnt understand what this if statement performing.

Comment: Again, **can you be more specific**? Do you know what *any* of it means?

Comment: @dangerous: the condition is true if `output` is still empty, or if it's not empty, then if `num` >= the last element in `output`. The `or` keyword guarantees that it doesn't try to do the `num >= output[-1]` part if `output` is empty, which is good, because indexing an empty list raises an IndexError.

Comment: @PM2Ring strictly speaking , the *lazy evaluation* of `or` guarantees it

Comment: @jonrsharpe: Certainly! I guess I should've used that phrase in my explanation, but I was trying to keep things simple...

Comment: @PM2Ring ok now I got it. Guys give me some time I am understanding jonrshape solution. I am totally new to python and programming.

Comment: @jonrsharpe - what is the need for adding sublist =[] in this statement this is the only place I am getting ` struck.  if sublist:
                output.extend((sublist, num))
                sublist = [] `

Comment: @dangerous: Try running the code on an input that makes multiple sublists (eg `543987`) with that `sublist = []` line commented out, and see what happens.

Comment: @jonrsharpe -                                                                                     `num = '45437'

final_lst = []

for i in num:
    final_lst.append(int(i))

new_lst = [final_lst[0]]

result = final_lst[1:]
 
sublist =[]    
         
for n in result:
    if  n > new_lst[-1]:
        new_lst.append(n)
    else:
        sublist.append(n) `  how do I modify this code to get the desired output. I know I am asking stupid questions, but it would be great if you could help me.

Comment: @dangerous what do you mean *"modify this code"*? I've *given* you the working code. Also, code (*particularly* Python) is very difficult to read in comments.

Comment: @jonrsharpe http://www.codeskulptor.org/#user39_TaQu1XFCk2_0.py. I am just curious on how should I modify my own code(shown in the link) to come up with a correct output. Yes your solution works, but I was coming up with my own version.

Comment: @jonrsharpe -  ok I will try to modify my code and post it as a solution

Comment: @jonrsharpe Your code doesnt work for the case. '455532123266' the output  should be [4, 5, [5, 5, 3, 2, 1], 2, 3, [2], 6, [6]]. The question says compare with previous number.

Comment: @ElizabethSusanJoseph that's not what the example in the question says

Answer (score 1):

well... Adding my 2 cents :-)

```
def custom_func(input_string):
    if not input_string:
        return []

    value = input_string[0]
    output_list = [int(value)]

    for char in input_string[1:]:
        if char > value:
            # Encountered a value higher than the past maximum
            output_list.append(int(char))
        else:
            if value == str(output_list[-1]):
                # First value that is lesser than the past maximum
                output_list.append([int(char)])
            else:
                # nth value which is lesser than the past maximum
                output_list[-1].append(int(char))
        value = char # updating the past maximum

    return output_list
```

Comment: Your code doesnt work for string = '5439487' and for an empty string string = ''

Comment: I am getting an output of `[5, [4, 3], 9, [4, 8, 7]]` for `543987`. I will add a fix for empty string :-)

Comment: output for  '5439487' should be [5,[4,3],9,[4], 8,7] as 8 is greater than 4.

Comment: 8 should be compared with 9 and not 4. Because, as OP has given, `'455532123266'` transforms to `[4, 5, [5, 5, 3, 2, 1, 2, 3, 2], 6, [6]]` which means we will break only when we found something bigger than the integer before the list. If the number is to compare with the element within the sub list, it would be `[4, 5, [5, 5, 3, 2, 1], 2, 3, [2], 6, [6]]` as  2 is bigger than 1.

Comment: "If a number x in the string is less than or equal to the preceding number y"  in this case. 8 should not compare with 9, it should compare with 4. In the case of '455532123266'  the third `5` is less than the second `5` so it goes into sublist.

Comment: Your code is clean and easily understandable. It would be nice if you could modify your code.

Comment: I will be happy to modify the code. It is just that I am confused is all. If it is just the preceding number, then for 455532`123266` should give [4, 5, [5, 5, 3, 2, `1], 2, 3, [2]`, 6, [6]] as number 2 at the index 9 is bigger than the predecessor 1 right?

Comment: The concept is. if the current number is less than the preceding number then make a sublist or else add that to the final list. in this case  [4, 5, [5, 5, 3, 2, 1], 2, 3, [2]. so 2 is greater than 1 so it is not addead to the sublist.

Comment: Please update the question :-) in the question, for the same input, the output is mentioned as `[4, 5, [5, 5, 3, 2, 1, 2, 3, 2], 6, [6]]`

Comment: oops I will up date the question :)

Answer (score 1):

This is the solution, you should consider.

```
num = '455532123266'
final_list = [];

prev = 0
sublist = []
for n in num:
    n = int(n)
    if (n > prev):
        if (sublist != []):
            final_list.append(sublist)
            sublist = []
        final_list.append(n)

    else:
        sublist.append(n)
    prev = n

if sublist != []:
    final_list.append(sublist)   

print final_list

[4, 5, [5, 5, 3, 2, 1], 2, 3, [2], 6, [6]]
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not very well-defined, in that the example input does not exactly clarify 2 issues:

- What should happen with '567' - should there be empty list after each number
- The example cannot tell if you are comparing the subsequent against the previous digit or the first digit of the decreasing subsequence!

<s>Thus here is my take, it is not necessarily the most pythonic, but I couldn't come up with more pythonic solution.</s>

```
def numbers_in_lists(string):
    current_min = -1  # larger than any digit
    rv = []
    current_list = []

    def push_sublist():
        if current_list:
            largest = current_list.pop(0)
            rv.extend([largest, current_list])

    for digit in map(int, string):
        if digit > current_min:
            push_sublist()
            current_list = []

        current_min = digit
        current_list.append(digit)

    push_sublist()  # if remaining
    return rv
```

As I suspected, the question was not at all clear. Considering how the example code worked, I devised a new algorithm

```
def numbers_in_lists(string):
    current_min = -1  # larger than any digit
    rv = []
    current_list = []

    def push_sublist():
        if current_list:
            largest = current_list.pop(0)
            rv.append(largest)
            if current_list:
                rv.append(current_list)

    for digit in map(int, string):
        if digit > current_min:
            push_sublist()
            current_list = []
            current_min = digit

        current_list.append(digit)

    push_sublist()  # if remaining
    return rv
```

Answer (score 0):

Mine is the lazy one:

```
def num_and_sublist_generator(iterable):
    start = -1
    sublist = []
    for n in iterable:
        if n > start:
            if sublist:
                yield sublist
                sublist = []
            start = n
            yield n
        else:
            sublist.append(n)
    if sublist:
        yield sublist

def numbers_in_lists(string):
    return list(num_and_sublist_generator(map(int, string)))
```

Answer (score 0):

I would consider doing it in more functional way.

```
def solve(input):
    pairs = zip(input, input[1:])
    sublist = [False] + map(lambda x: x[0] > x[1], pairs)

    result = []
    for (val, to_sublist) in zip(input, sublist):
        if not to_sublist:
            result.append(val)
        else:
            if isinstance(result[-1], list):
                result[-1].append(val)
            else:
                result.append([val])
    return result
```

This is allows for separation of checking to_sublist predicate and actual building of resulting data structure. To my understanding first number never goes to sublist so it always starts with False.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution I could think of that follows the actual problem statement is:

```
def numbers_in_lists(string):
    output = []
    sublist = []
    for number in [int(c) for c in string]: # Every number in the string should be inserted into the list.
        if output and number <= output[-1]:
            """
            - If a number x in the string is less than or equal
              to the preceding number y, the number x should be
              inserted into a sublist.
            - Continue adding the following numbers to the sublist
              until reaching a number z that is greater than the number y.
            """
            sublist.append(number)
        else:
            """
            - Then add this number z to the normal list and continue.
            """
            if sublist:
                output.append(sublist)
                sublist = []
            output.append(number)
    if sublist:
        output.append(sublist)
    return output
```

Comment: what is the specific need for adding if sublist and if output in your code.

Comment: what is the need for adding this a empty sublist =[] here ` if sublist:
                output.append(sublist)
                sublist = []'

Comment: @dangerous the same as in my code (this one just has the predicates reversed) - we've added the old `sublist` to the `output`, so now we create a new one for the next time we need it.

Comment: @jonrsharpe ok now I got it.

Answer (score 0):

One other way of doing it... Might be confusing though

```
_val = int(string[0])
my_lis = [_val]
temp_li = []
for  i in string[1:]:
    _cval = int(i)
    if _cval > _val:
        if temp_li:
            my_lis.append(temp_li[:])
            temp_li = []
        my_lis.append(_cval)
        _val = _cval
    else:
        temp_li.append(_cval)
        _val =  temp_li[0]
if temp_li: my_lis.append(temp_li[:])# last value
print string
print my_lis
```

Comment: No need for thanks :-) this is what stackoverflow is for... You take care of important things and some one will take care of smaller things that need to be taken care of :-)